# where on heroku can i enter DNS records for whitelabelling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, sendgrid

I have searched high and low for how to add DNS records to my heroku app for whitelabelling.  I am simply going round in circles following the same links to support articles, but there seems to be no information.  I am trying to complete the rails tutorial account activation email with sendgrid and am on the stage of whitelabelling the sendgrid account and verifying the whitelabel. i am on the screen on sendgrid where it give you soem information to add to the DNS records of your app. however i have no idea what to do with this information. i think i need to insert it somewhere into my heroky app, but the documentation on sendgrid and heroku do not address this issue specifically. the information that needs to be transferred to heroku from sendgrid is as follows:

```
Type: CNAME, HOST: still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com, DATA: u6460287.wl038.sendgrid.net

Type: CNAME, HOST: s1._domainkey.com, DATA: s1.domainkey.u6460287.wl038.sendgrid.net

Type: CNAME HOST: s2._domainkey.com, DATA: s2.domainkey.u6460287.wl038.sendgrid.net
```

has anyone ever completed the whitelabel process with sendgrid for a heroku app? if so please advise as what i should do next. thanks.

Comment: You need to enter those records where you registered your domain. eg: GoDaddy.

Comment: @coderhs . i dont know what "enter those records" means. can you be more specific?  i am deploying on heroku. Where on heroku should i enter the information? i have looked all overthe site for somewhere to enter these records, but i have found nothing and none of the documentation seems to talk about this. i am following this part of the tutorial blindly and do not understand fully what i am doing.